# How to verify a signature in openssl consisting of ECDSA [r, s] values?

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I am using Bouncy Castle/Java to generate signature, as it gives 2 big integers with R, S values. Now requirement is to verify that using OpenSSL commands.

```
public static String[] generateSignature(String message) {
    final ECDSASigner ecdsaSigner = new ECDSASigner();

    try {

        // Get private key

        BCECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey = (BCECPrivateKey) JKSUtil.getPrivateKey();
        if(ecPrivateKey != null) {
            // Get parameter spec from private key
            ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ecPrivateKey.getParameters();

            // Create ECDomain object
            ECDomainParameters params = new ECDomainParameters(ecSpec.getCurve(), ecSpec.getG(), // G
                    ecSpec.getN()); // n

            // Create private key parameters
            ECPrivateKeyParameters priKey = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(ecPrivateKey.getD(), // d
                    params);

            ecdsaSigner.init(true, priKey);

            // Create digest message (hash) for the actual message. 
            SHA256Digest keyDigest = new SHA256Digest();
            keyDigest.update(message.getBytes(), 0, message.getBytes().length);
            byte[] digestMessage = new byte[keyDigest.getDigestSize()];
            keyDigest.doFinal(digestMessage, 0);
            BigInteger[] sig = ecdsaSigner.generateSignature(digestMessage);

            // Convert signature to base64
            String[] base64Sig = new String[2];
            base64Sig[0] = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sig[0].toByteArray()));
            base64Sig[1] = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sig[1].toByteArray()));
            String signature = base64Sig[0]+"|"+base64Sig[1];

            System.out.println(signature);

            return base64Sig;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return null;
}
```

For example: my message which I want to sign is `"Name is RS"`, running the above utility returns me the R and S values with delimiter '|' encoded in base64 as

```
ALk8VQP5XLmCIe0Kh3IE74fS55huvzv0jw==|Hj+UsStEbDYOqX98EszSET2ULE3D9kCV
```

Now on openssl side:

```
openssl enc  -base64 -d -in signature.txt -out signatureToVerify.bin -A
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify eckey.pub -signature signatureToVerify.bin message.txt
```

Its not able to verify and I am stuck - keep getting the error as "Verification Failure" on openssl side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL requires a X9.62 signature. This consists of the DER encoding of the two integer values R and S. If you look at the Bouncy Castle source code for the provider class `SignatureSpi` you will find:

```
ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
v.add(new ASN1Integer(r));
v.add(new ASN1Integer(s));
byte[] derEncodedSignature = new DERSequence(v).getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);
```

which is what you should use to encode the signature using Bouncy Castle. Here `r` and `s` should be the `BigInteger` values you get in the two element result array.

As you might have guessed, you can also use the Java JCA `Signature` class instead, which will produce the same signature encoding. If required or wanted you could use the BouncyCastle implementation as underlying provider by registering / indicating the provider. Funny enough the Bouncy Castle library now has a pretty fast EC implementation which beats the Oracle provided implementation, even though that is in native code.

---

The *binary* output is directly compatible with the signature input for OpenSSL. To create a text string it is possible to encode the byte array to a base 64 string (preferably without line endings, e.g. `Base64.encode(derEncodedsignature)`), which then has to be decoded by `openssl enc  -base64 -A -d -in signature.txt -out signatureToVerify.bin`

Comment: Thank you Maarteen. Let me try this way.

Comment: So base 64 encode / decode it. It is now a single byte array, right?

Comment: Its prolly issue with openssl command, let me fix that. And will keep this thread posted on how verification goes. And finally update this thread with full working code which can help other folks. Thanks a ton for your help Maarten, you are a GEM.

Comment: Don't you want to convert the signature rather than the message? Your input for just base 64 decoding is `message.txt` and the output after decoding is `signatureToVerify.bin`? Surely that cannot be right?

Comment: Openssl Issue was fixed, it was because of space, I had to use -A to avoid that "openssl enc -base64 -d -in signature.txt -out signatureToVerify.bin -A". But signature verification has failed - openssl gave me error "Verification Failure". Command I am using to verify is "openssl dgst -SHA256 -verify eckey.pub -signature signatureToVerify.bin data.txt"

Comment: You know, I did fully test my answer even against `openssl` so unfortunately there is still something wrong on your side :) I didn't base 64 encode / decode the signature, but that should not have any influence if done right.

Comment: @user3836681+ possible difference: `enc -a/-base64 -d` requires its input be one or more _line(s)_ i.e. terminated by Unix-LF or Windows-CRLF. `-A` accepts (or creates) a _string_ without such termination. Especially on Windows it's easy to create a file with tools like notepad that does not have its only (or last) line terminated, and visually comparing the contents of files you can't see the last terminator. (Maarten: note I've broken at-less exchange.)

Comment: I did use a different base64 command line (just `base64` instead of `enc -base64`. No idea if that matters at all. Aren't those little encoding differences "fun" :|

Comment: That one _doesn't_ make any difference. `openssl base64` is internally translated to `openssl enc -base64` just like `openssl aes-128-cbc` is translated to `openssl enc -aes-128-cbc` and so on. I like to spell out the `enc` because it reminds people (possibly including me) which man page to look at. And `-base64` and `-a` are aliases for the same option. (But not `-A`.)